# ASP.NET Core 3.1 using XmlSerializerFormatters()

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I currently have an application based on .Net Core 2.2 which works. I need to move this project forward to .Net Core 3.1 but I cannot seem to get the XML Deserialized in the controller. In both apps I created a WCF connected service successfully. The WDSL now has more classes defined but are basically the same. I diffed the files and
Left handside is newly generated fill:

```
<     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
---
>     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1-preview-30310-0943")]
```

This repeats with every class in Reference.cs. My problem is my Postman tests fail with the new controllers. By using Calculatus Eliminatus I have managed to track down the difference, The old parsing would accept:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedServiceRequestX xmlns="http://somename.com/api/01">
    <Timestamp>2021-04-05T16:35:43</Timestamp>
    <ApiKey>TopSecretKey</ApiKey>
    <CustomerId>ABC</CustomerId>
</ConnectedServiceRequestX>
```

The new parser only works if the posted XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedServiceRequestX>
    <Timestamp xmlns="http://somename.com/api/01">2021-04-05T16:35:43</Timestamp>
    <ApiKey xmlns="http://somename.com/api/01">TopSecretKey</ApiKey>
    <CustomerId xmlns="http://somename.com/api/01">ABC</CustomerId>
</ConnectedServiceRequestX>
```

The new parser throws an exception when putting xmlns="http://somename.com/api/01" at class level XML Item. I need to support the older XML input as I have no ownership of the system accessing our service. This is a case where a big corporation is dictating the interface that they will use to access our data and we are a small outfit.

I am inclined to think there is some option I can supply to .XmlSerializerFormatters() such that the xmlns will default to what namespace is provided on the class level XML Item. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConnectedServiceRequestX));
            ConnectedServiceRequestX request = (ConnectedServiceRequestX)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://somename.com/api/01")]
    public class ConnectedServiceRequestX
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jdweng. If you look at my solution it is basically what you are suggesting only I used XmlRootAttribute and not XmlRoot.

Comment: I just saw same.  But somebody gave me negative points.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the diffs between the Generated files (April 2019 and today) I noticed a one line difference preceding some of the classes. There are 60 plus classes in the C# file generated from the WDSL (I apologize for not noticing earlier). Anyhow, The line is as follows:

```
 [XmlRootAttribute("ConnectedServiceRequestX", Namespace="http://somename.com/api/01", IsNullable = false)]
```

These lines we added at some point after the class generation but prior to their initial entry into source control. They require:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

to be added as well. What this does is allows the xmlns attribute to be placed in the outer tag (Class Item tag) and not have to be replicated in the inner tags as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedServiceRequestX xmlns="http://somename.com/api/01">
    <Timestamp>2021-04-05T16:35:43</Timestamp>
    <ApiKey>TopSecretKey</ApiKey>
    <CustomerId>ABC</CustomerId>
</ConnectedServiceRequestX>
```

Which is how my legacy tests with Postman were designed. I wrote (generated) this code when I was learning ASP.Net Web Services and I do not remember modifying the generated files to get the Connected Service / XML Post to work. So the short answer is when generating code (adding a Connected Service - WCF/WDSL) with Visual Studio there still may be some modifications to the Reference.cs file which allow more friendly XML to be posted to the endpoints.

I am now up and running (ASP.NET Core 3.1) using my legacy tests which give me confidence to go to production with the updated app. I hope this helps others.